# Why not use a community-wiki post to aggregate data?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, community-wiki

I know this is not a canonically accepted use of Stack Exchange, but for [How far is the heat limit from the power limit on speedlights?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/67815/27832) the first answerer (who obviously has not yet been fully indoctrinated ;) wonders in a comment, "Perhaps you could obtain the data by asking the community to perform various tests on different flashes and then collate the results?"

I am likewise wondering: Why not?  Isn't that a fair community-wiki Q&A?

Update: Following AJHenderson's answer I figured [I might as well just try it, so have a look](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/67961/27832).

Let the re-education begin....

Answer (score 1):

A request for data isn't an answer, but could be suggested in a comment.  The problem would be trying to build the answer.  Theoretically, this could actually be done via a community-wiki answer with a grid of heat to power data for different lights as such a grid would answer the question, but it would be a bit unusual.

It really comes down to the fact that answers should be answers to the question.  An "answer" that suggests a means to answer isn't an answer, it's a comment.  An answer that supplies a single data point isn't really an answer yet either as it doesn't address the question, but assembling an answer from multiple users is potentially viable.

Someone would then likely have to update it later with analysis of the data to really fill out the answer.

Comment: Nothing like an unusual person to try an unusual approach ;)  I just put up a CW answer with *two* data points, so maybe it will be easier to critique ... or see it actually work!